# Cannot create foder

Tags: 14.04, npm

I am running the following command `sudo npm install node-sass --save-dev`
and the process fails with the error as follows :-

`build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /home/anit/Desktop/theInjuredLion/natours/node_modules/node-sass/build
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/anit/Desktop/theInjuredLion/natours/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-58-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/anit/Desktop/theInjuredLion/natours/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /home/anit/Desktop/theInjuredLion/natours/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v8.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1`

Answer (score 0):

I think You need to reclaim ownership of the .npm directory.

```
sudo chown -R $(User) ~/.npm
```

and need the write permission in node_modules directory:

```
sudo chown -R $(User) /home/anit/Desktop/
```

or

```
sudo chown -R $(User) /home/anit/Desktop/theInjuredLion/natours/
```